# Counting integers related to Bézout's identity

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am reading a proof on a double sums and I don't understand. Here is the context:

Let $p,q$ two fixed integers and $k\in[1,\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\rfloor-1],l\in[1,\lfloor\frac{N}{q}\rfloor-1].$

Now he said that there is for all $n\in[-\lfloor\frac{N}{pq}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{N}{pq}\rfloor]$ (interval of integers) $$\gcd(p,q)\times \lfloor\frac{N}{pq}\rfloor$$ couples $(k,l)$ such that $$n\gcd(p,q)=pk-ql$$

It's seems related to Bezout's identity but I don't see how to prove this.

Comment: There must be some limitation on $(k,l).$ Otherwise you get infinitely many solutions with $(k+mq,\,l+mp),\;m\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier yes, I forgot to write the limitation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started trying to prove this when I realized it's not always true as currently stated. For a fairly simple example, let $p = q = 2$ and $N = 4$. Then $\gcd(p,q) = 2$, $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor = 2$, $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{q}\right\rfloor = 2$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{pq}\right\rfloor = 1$. Also,

$$k\in \left[1,\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor-1\right] = [1,2-1] = [1,1] \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$l\in \left[1,\left\lfloor\frac{N}{q}\right\rfloor-1\right] = [1,2-1] = [1,1] \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Next, note that

$$n\gcd(p,q)=pk-ql \; \Rightarrow \; 2n = 2k - 2l \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

The range for $n$ becomes

$$n\in\left[-\left\lfloor \frac{N}{pq} \right\rfloor,\left\lfloor \frac{N}{pq} \right\rfloor\right] = [-1,1] \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

The stated total # of solutions becomes

$$\gcd(p,q) \times \left\lfloor \frac{N}{pq} \right\rfloor = 2 \times 1 = 2 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

However, as $k = l = 1$ are the only allowed values to choose from, the RHS of \eqref{eq3} has a sole value of $0$, giving just $n = 0$ as the only value allowed in the range given in \eqref{eq4}. However, this means there is just $1$ couple of $(k,l)$, which doesn't match the value of $2$ given in \eqref{eq5} as the expected number of solutions.

It seems either something is incorrect in the provided details or additional conditions are required for what you're trying to prove to always be true. As you only say that $p$ and $q$ are fixed, perhaps you're meant to show some $N$ exists which satisfies all of the conditions? I believe this may be the case, but I won't try to prove it unless you confirm this is actually what is required.

Comment: @TheVie You are welcome. I appreciate the extra details, but I'm not clear on a few things. When you ask about writing $pk - ql$ as an "unique integer", among what group of values is it meant to be unique? Also, for $pk - ql = f_{p,q}(n)$, do you mean something like $pk(n) - ql(n) = f_{p,q}(n)$, i.e., where the $k$ and $l$ values are functions of $n$ and, thus, determined by its value? Also, based on what you were originally requesting, it seemed you wanted multiple possibel values, or is to be just a single value?

Comment: @TheVie Thanks for the example. I believe I now have a better idea of what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, it's not quite as simple to do with $pk-ql$ as you've seen. However, I think it could be done, but with different limits than what you propose. I suggest you work with it yourself (e.g., try a few small examples explicitly) to see how you may adjust those limits appropriately. If you still having difficulties & think we may help, I suggest creating a new post, linking to this one, explain what you're doing & then asking for the limits or perhaps how to adjust the best ones you have.

Comment: @TheVie To clarify what I wrote above, I don't believe fixed limits will work in all cases for $pk - ql$. Instead, they would need to vary somewhat to accommodate the different starting positions for $k$ and $l$ for a specific value of $n$, $p$ and $q$. However, I don't know if you consider using variable limits to be a valid option for what you're doing.